# django 1.6 with mezzanine - urls not working, Maximum recursion error

Tags: django, mezzanine

The same code is working locally

but the same is not working on the server.

I think it is definitely urls problem.

Need more information ? How can it work locally and not on server ?

Its not about gunicorn etc because I even tried with python manage.py runserver with debug=true but even thats giving same error.

Comment: paste the whole error traceback please

Comment: When debug=true and running using python manage.py runserver, error is "reverse for xxx not found" - I think bcoz urls.py is not loaded properly.

Comment: could you show the whole error traceback? then i could tell you where to fix.

Comment: when is ``Maximum recursion error`` and when is ``reverse for xxx not found`` happenning? i am confused..

Comment: @doniyor When running using debug=False I am getting maximum error. translation/trans_null.py", line 25, in <lambda>
    get_language = lambda: settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object. Please let me know if you still need full stack.

Comment: I think, you need to rename ``get_language`` lambda function to something else like ``get_language_forme`` because ``get_language`` is already used in ``django.utils.translation.get_language()``. let me know if it worked

Comment: Ok thanks, I will be back tomorrow with more details and will tag your name to tell you that I updated. Bye for now.